# How to send asynchronous requests (more than 7) and handle result?

Tags: java, android

Need to get html pages and parse their queries can be quite. Something like:

```
showProgressDialog();
for(Object obj: objects) {
     new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              String url = obj.getUrl();
              String html = getHtml(url);
              db.saveToDB(parse(html));
          }
     });
}
stopProgressDialog();
updateListView(); // using date from db
```

but how do i know when threads finished their work. Thing about `AsyncTask` but in documents written that they are not suitable for this. Please give me some example or a hint that it is better to use in android.

Comment: Look at using a library like Volley: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: @Ken Wolf Thanks, i used volley in my project but for some reason it does not fit me in this task,

Comment: @Tany can you please tll why `AsyncTask ` is not suitable  ??? if possible thn ?